# Piping echo output to another echo

Tags: bash, shell, echo

Is there any way to pipe echo output to another echo and slice it without using variable?

For example:
This can be done without using pipe

```
var="heyyy hello there HRU?"
echo "${var:11}"
```

But we don't use **var** while using pipe...

```
echo "heyyy hello there HRU?" | echo "${?:11}"
```

How to capture the output from previous command and slice it as we use do using variable? Is there any way to do it?

I know it can be done using multiple commands like **"sed", "awk", "cut"**,  etc., but I just wanted to know if there any way to do it with echo.

Comment: echo doesn't read stdin.

Comment: The [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem.

Comment: No there isn't a way. You can create your own "echo" but that's no longer "echo".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capture it in a variable.

```
echo "heyyy hello there HRU?" | { var=$(cat); echo "${var:11}"; }
```

Comment: Is there any way to do without using variable?? @KamilCuk

Comment: `any way to do without` Do what exactly? As for doing `${var:11}` without a variable: no, it's called _variable_ expansion. And you already know that: `I know it can be done using multiple commands like "sed", "awk", "cut"`

Answer (score 2):

`echo` doesn't use `stdin` !. It can just print arguments given to it. So what you're trying won't work in short.

`echo` -- write arguments to the standard output

**Refer Man Page** : https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/echo.1p.html

```
STDIN
       Not used.
```

Comment: Do you mean that we can't use **echo** command to capture previous output ?? @Akshay Hegde

Comment: Yes this doesn't capture stdin kindly read man page link given above.

Comment: Maybe **echo** command doesn't capture stdin. But there'll be someway to capture it and pass it as an argument to it that's what I've been trying to find out. Anyways thank you :D @Akshay Hegde

Comment: @Raj you mean something like this `echo "heyyy hello there HRU?" | echo "$(</dev/stdin)"` again this is variable BTW

Comment: Yeahh you almost got that. This is what I wanted to know. But can we do slicing with this?? If so, how to do that! @Akshay Hegde

Comment: @Raj FYI `${parameter:offset}`, here parameter can be either shell parameters or array