# Bash - echoing captured variable removes newline

Tags: bash

I have a private key I want to both print to stdout and transform to a public key which should also be printed.

Based on this answer: [Piping echo output to another echo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67952051/piping-echo-output-to-another-echo)

```bash
echo "pkcs12 here" |\ 
  openssl rsa |\
  { var=$(cat); echo "$var\n$(echo $var | openssl rsa -pubout)"; }
```

This works fine in ZSH, but I've found out that in Bash the innermost `echo $var` removes newline characters, which causes the openssl command to fail

Now that we know what I want to do, let's simplify the problem a bit:

```bash
$ echo "a\nb\nc"
a
b
c
```

```bash
echo "a\nb\nc" | { var=$(cat); echo "$(echo $var)"; }
a b c
```

How do I preserve new lines in the simplified example?

Comment: Need to quote `$var` in echo

Comment: See ["I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` shows something else"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else) and ["When should I double-quote a parameter expansion?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55023461/when-should-i-double-quote-a-parameter-expansion) (short answer: almost always).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
echo "a\nb\nc" | { var=$(cat); echo "$(echo -e "$var")"; }
a
b  
c
```

---

Learn how to quote properly in shell, it's very important :

> "Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
> http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
> http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
> https://web.archive.org/web/20230224010517/https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words
> [when-is-double-quoting-necessary](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)